How do I get "git reset" to also automatically reset submodules?
I'm working on some projects with a number of submodules, so it's nice to be able to reset the submodules when working on the main project.  One way to solve this is by adding a flag to the reset to tell it to recurse into the submodules and update them as well:
git reset --hard --recurse-submodules <COMMIT>

It seems like there should be a config option for this flag, but there doesn't appear to be anything in the man page.

There is a configuration option described in the online manual that turns on recursion into submodules for a lot of git commands:
git config --global submodule.recurse true

This particular option has a lot of knock-on effects, so it's good to be aware of that.
